# In scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram, setting 'ax' or 'above_threshold_color' throws an unexpected keyword error

Tags: python, scipy, dendrogram, keyword-argument

I'm using scipy 0.16.0 on a Windows 8.1 machine and getting an unexpected keyword error when I try to run the dendrogram() function from scipy with passed settings for 'ax' or 'above_threshold_color'. Here's the error:

```
TypeError: dendrogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'above_threshold_color'
```

This is despite the fact that both 'ax' and 'above_threshold_color' are clearly indicated as potential keyword arguments in the documents which can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html). I don't absolutely have to use these variables but I don't understand why just these two are causing me problems. My only idea was that a certain mixture of settings could potentially cause an error in the graphing, but there is no indication of this in the documentation. Is it just a bug?

Comment: "threshold" only has one H after the S..

Comment: Alternatively, if it's not simply the typo, is it possible you're using an older version of `scipy`?  That argument was only introduced in 16.0, I think, so if you're using 0.15.1 or earlier you wouldn't have it.

Comment: DSM, you were right about the typo, but that was just a typo in my message here on SO. It still doesn't work with in just one 'h'. Also, I have scipy version 0.16.0.

Comment: Then you're going to need to prove it, I'm afraid. :-)  Please create a small [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which starts with `print(scipy.version.version)` and then (say) `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(0, above_threshold_color=True)`, and show the output (a direct copy and paste, don't retype it as you said you did for the first one.)

Comment: Thank you very much DSM! You were right, it was a scipy version issue. The reason I was confused about which version I was running is because I got mixed up between the version on my computer (scipy 0.13.2) and my deployment virtual server (scipy 0.16.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSM was right in the comments above, this was just a version issue.